# Selenium implicit and explicit waits not working / has no effect

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://google.com")

#driver.implicitly_wait(10)

WebDriverWait(driver,10)

print("waiting 10 sec")

driver.quit()
```

It just quits after page loading. the waits have no effect at all!

demo : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GocfsDZFqk8&feature=youtu.be

any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can use pageload timeout

Comment: But y you need to add wait before

Comment: Tried that too.no luck.

Comment: time.sleep(5)  try this ,, it's hard wait but in your case it will work

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want a pause 10 seconds, use `time.sleep()`:

```
import time

time.sleep(10) # take a pause 10 seconds
```

***Note:*** `WebDriverWait(driver,10)` doesn't work like that. Instead you can use it like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

# this will wait at least 10 seconds until url will contain "your_url"
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.url_contains(("your_url")))
```

but it will not wait exactly 10 seconds, only until `expected_conditions` will be satisfied.

***Also:*** as source code us tells:

```
def implicitly_wait(self, time_to_wait):
    """
    Sets a sticky timeout to implicitly wait for an element to be found,
       or a command to complete. This method only needs to be called one
       time per session. To set the timeout for calls to
       execute_async_script, see set_script_timeout.

    :Args:
     - time_to_wait: Amount of time to wait (in seconds)

    :Usage:
        driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    """
    ...
```

`driver.implicitly_wait(10)` also is used for waiting elements, not to pause script.

***PS:*** it is always a good practice to use `WebDriverWait` instead of hard pause, because with `WebDriverWait` your test will be more quickly, since you don't have to wait the whole amount of time, but only until `expected_conditions` will be satisfied. As I understood, you are just playing arround at the moment, but for the future `WebDriverWait` is better to use.

Comment: For the `driver.implicitly_wait(10)`, what's the difference between **waiting elements** and **pause script**.

Comment: @Tengerye when you *pause a script*, script will do nothing a given ammount of time(for example 10 sec). And *waiting elements* with `driver.implicitly_wait(10)` will set a 'mechanism' to wait for element to be interactable. For example clickable, or visible and so on. In this case programm will wait *max* 10 sec until given condition will be satisfied. Hope this was more clear.

Answer (score 5):

At least with Python and Chrome driver, my experience is that even when using
WebDriverWait you STILL need to use time.sleep for things to work reliably.  using implicitly_wait doesnt work.  I need to put time.sleep(1) after each operation, or sometimes things don't fire off.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I do not see how this answers the question at the top of this page, but it should. Please [edit] according to [answer] or delete the answer. Otherwise it risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

By using this `WebDriverWait(driver,10)` , you have declared the **Explicit wait**. This is just the declaration , you are not using explicit wait at all.

For make use of **Explicit wait**, you will have to bind the above code with **EC** which is `Expected condition`.

Something like :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, 'q')))
element.send_keys("Hi Google")
```

You can refer this link for **explicit wait** :  [Explicit wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Note that `time.sleep(10)`  is `worst/extreme` type of explicit wait which sets the condition to an exact time period to wait.  There are some convenience methods provided that help you write code that will wait only as long as required. WebDriverWait in combination with ExpectedCondition is one way this can be accomplished.

Answer (score 2):

So we had this same problem, what we did was modify the driver class in selenium with a decorator to sleep for .44 seconds on functions that we modified in the get_driver() function. In this case we wanted to wait to find elements by class, name and id before selenium inputted our desired content. Worked like a charm.

```
def sleep_decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        time.sleep(.44)                      # Added side-effect
        return func(*args, **kwargs)         # Modified return
    return wrapper


def get_driver():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.find_element_by_id = sleep_decorator(driver.find_element_by_id)
    driver.find_element_by_name = sleep_decorator(driver.find_element_by_name)
    driver.find_element_by_class_name = sleep_decorator(driver.find_element_by_class_name)
    driver.find_elements_by_id = sleep_decorator(driver.find_elements_by_id)
    driver.find_elements_by_name = sleep_decorator(driver.find_elements_by_name)
    driver.find_elements_by_class_name = sleep_decorator(driver.find_elements_by_class_name)
    return driver
```